# Creating an Add-In for Outlook on the web

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I'd like to create an add-in for Outlook on the web (not the desktop client, the web client.) [From this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-add-ins-in-outlook-on-the-web-8f2ce816-5df4-44a5-958c-f7f9d6dabdce) it is evidently possible, but I cannot find any info on how to actually create such an add in. Can someone point me in the right direction? Is there any way to make add-ins of this kind that work on native clients on iOS and Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator) to create an Outlook add-in. Any add-in you create will be supported across Desktop, Web and Mac. You can use the [MobileFormFactor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/mobileformfactor) in your add-in to support the add-in for iOS and Android as well.